# ".modal is not a function" Bootstrap 3.3.7, jQuery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, show

I'm capturing a field via jQuery

```
$addPanel = $("div#add-panel");
```

Then

```
$addPanel.modal("show");
```

However, when the command is executed I get an error on my console:

```
Index.js:148 Uncaught TypeError: $addPanel.modal is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Index.js:148)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

I've already verified the import sequence on my _layout file (using asp.MVC), already tried the jQuery.noConflit(); comand. No success.

Here is the HTML from the captured div:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-panel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Cadastrar nova nota fiscal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Número</label>
                        <input id="number" placeholder="Insira o número" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Série</label>
                        <input id="serie" placeholder="Insira a série" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Data</label>
                        <input id="date" placeholder="Insira a data" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Fornecedor</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="supplierName" placeholder="Insira o nome do novo fornecedor" />
                            <select id="supplierID" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" class="empty">Selecione o fornecedor ou cadastre em +</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="supplierAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-default" title="Novo Fornecedor">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Novo
                                </button>
                                <button id="supplierSave" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-success" title="Salvar">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> <span>Salvar</span>
                                </button>
                                <button id="supplierCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-danger" title="Cancelar">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancelar
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Descrição</label>
                        <textarea id="note" placeholder="Insira uma anotação" maxlength="200" class="form-control" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm-button">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap javascript included? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ `.modal()` should work unless you dont have the Bootstrap library

Comment: Yes, it is on my bundle:
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
Wich is being called on my _layout file just after the jquery:
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems fine and working on fiddle. Try either:

1. Use `$(document).ready()` to wrap the JS code.
2. Load jQuery from HTML and check if it works (if it does, something's wrong on your end when importing jQuery).
3. Make sure in bootstrap CSS file is loaded before the JS file.

If none of the above worked consider sharing more of the `index.js` code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $addPanel = $("div#add-panel");
  $addPanel.modal("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="add-panel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Cadastrar nova nota fiscal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Número</label>
              <input id="number" placeholder="Insira o número" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Série</label>
              <input id="serie" placeholder="Insira a série" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Data</label>
              <input id="date" placeholder="Insira a data" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Fornecedor</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="supplierName" placeholder="Insira o nome do novo fornecedor" />
                <select id="supplierID" class="form-control">
                  <option value="" class="empty">Selecione o fornecedor ou cadastre em +</option>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="supplierAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-default" title="Novo Fornecedor">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Novo
                                </button>
                                <button id="supplierSave" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-success" title="Salvar">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> <span>Salvar</span>
                </button>
                <button id="supplierCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-group btn-danger" title="Cancelar">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancelar
                </button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Descrição</label>
              <textarea id="note" placeholder="Insira uma anotação" maxlength="200" class="form-control" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm-button">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Loaded jQuery on HTML, worked.
Checked my bundles again and discovered a typing error.
Thank you.